# React JS MUI X datagrid how to override the pagination with option for the user to select from list of days and load the data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

MUI X datagrid how to override the pagination with option for the user to select from list of days and load the data

Implement the datagrid component with custom pagination. So that user can have option to select the number of days to load the datagrid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.